# How to display a hidden carousel slider on button click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to show a carousel slider on button click. I have set the carousel `display` as `none` and tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#showMyCarousel').click(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').toggle("show");
  });
});
```

to display `myCarousel` on click of `showMyCarousel` and it doesn't work properly.

Whenever I click on the button my carousel comes up but hides again within few seconds.

Comment: What carousel are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 carousel slide

Comment: Can you post a minimal example showing the issue at https://jsfiddle.net/ and add a link to it to your question?

Comment: jquery toggle only toggles elements, and the parameters it should receive are `.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )`. [See the full doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Try using `$('#myCarousel').show();`

Comment: @AdrianHeine, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/nbk1Ltjm/ ... It needs little correction, can u pls add external ref for bootstrap n jquery

Comment: @junkystu, I tried with .show() too, doesn't help. In both the cases the slider comes up but disappears after few seconds.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to remove the 15+ loading errors from missing external references. Changed button to be type button, added return false to button event as the page was reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: OnClick event was causing a post back and was setting the carousel display as none. To prevent post back and reloading of controls return false for OnClick event of the button.